# Streaming Operator bytes to 16-bit words reverse byte order

Tags: system-verilog, test-bench

Using this systemverilog snip to change bytes to 16 bit words.

```
module tb();
  logic [31:0] myWordQueue[$];
  byte  myByteQueue [$];

  initial begin
    $display("starting");
    
    myByteQueue[0] = 8'h44;
    myByteQueue[1] = 8'h94;
    myByteQueue[2] = 8'h03;
    myByteQueue[3] = 8'h00;
    myByteQueue[4] = 8'hb8;
    myByteQueue[5] = 8'h99;
    myByteQueue[6] = 8'h03;
    myByteQueue[7] = 8'h00;
    
    myWordQueue = {>>32{myByteQueue}};
    
    $display("myWordQueue[0] = %h", myWordQueue[0] );
    $display("myWordQueue[1] = %h", myWordQueue[1] );
  end
endmodule
```

Which produces

```
# myWordQueue[0] = 44940300
# myWordQueue[1] = b8990300
```

How do I change the streaming operator such that the pattern produced is:

```
myWordQueue[0] =  00039444
myWordQueue[1] =  000399b8
```

Also tried

```
myWordQueue = {<<32{myByteQueue}};
```

Also does not produce the result I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to nest the streaming operator. First to reverse the byte order, then to reverse the word order.

```
myWordQueue = {<<32{  {<<8{myByteQueue}} }}   ;
```

Note that when using right-to-left streaming `>>N` the `N` has no effect.